# Puzzle: Can you find an elementary proof that every $n \gt 6$ can be represented as a sum of $O(\log n)$ distinct primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, puzzle

Can you find an elementary proof that every $n \gt 6$ can be represented as a sum of $O(\log n)$ distinct primes?  For example, $11 = 11$, $12 = 5 + 7$, $13 = 2 + 11$, $14 = 2 + 5 + 7$.  On the other hand, 6 cannot be represented as the sum of distinct primes.  [Vinogradov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_theorem) implies this but I am expecting a simple demonstration.  I can prove the statement to my own satisfaction but I think it is an interesting problem and I am wondering what is the simplest and most rigorous approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), there is a prime between $n/2$ and $n$. Pick the largest such prime and recurse. The number goes down by a factor of at least $2$ in each step, so we can take at most $O(\log n)$ rounds.

Comment: Problem: what if you keep reducing $n$ recursively and, say, end up with $6$? This occurs when you have consecutive [sexy primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime), e.g. $29-23=6$.

Comment: @anon: The proof can be fixed by using Bertand's postulate to pick a prime between $(n-6)/2$ and $n-6$.

Comment: Very concise explanation.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. Concise, yes :), but I am afraid it is actually a little far from rigorous. I am still trying to fill the gap anon mentioned. TonyK's fix seems to work fine, but I am not yet sure that all cases are taken care of. (I wish you had posed the problem without the restriction that the primes are distinct ;))